# Using LINQ to query an IDictionary with Lambda expression

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

Why is this not returning the proper string even though the dictionary is showing the correct key/value pairs while debugging?

```
IDictionary<string, string> states = 
                   AFS.MvcApplication.UnitedStates.StateDictionary;

string stateAbbrev = 
               states.Where(x => x.Key == State).Select(x => x.Value).ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `ToString`, since the result of `Select` is an `IEnumerable<string>`. This should work:

```
string stateAbbrev = states.Where(x => x.Key == State).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
string stateAbbrev =  states[State];
```